# How to have return statement with prompt

Tags: javascript, html

I have a prompt that asks various questions from an array I want it so that if user presses cancel returns 0 and stops. When I have the return, nothing pops up. Am I able to have a return statement or is that not possible.

```js
let promptText = questions[0];
for (let i = 1; i < questions.length; i++) {
  let userAnswer = prompt(promptText);
  if (userAnswer === null) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    promptText = questions[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: is this code resides inside a function?

Comment: @brk yeah with questions as a parameter

Comment: It looks like you'd want to show something based on the return value outside of this function. Notice, that you can return from a function only once, and if user answers to all questions you will have only the last answer to return. You've to change the logic so, that remove the loop from the function, and call this function within the loop.

Comment: "*so that if user presses cancel returns 0 and stops*" this is what it does.   "*When I have the return, nothing pops up*" - is that *after* the prompt for the question?   It might help if you included the code around this - ie the function declaration and how you call it.   Ideally a complete snippet that *demonstrates* the issue.  see [mcve].  As-is, it appears to be doing what you want.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please click [edit], scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and make it a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

First: Please post more code. What is the content of the array? You use a return-statement, so this must be a function. So the code is incomplete without function() { ... } and a function call.

Questions:

1. have you more then 1 questions in `questions[]`? If not, nothing happens! Your for-loop starts at 1. And `question.length` was 1. 1 was not lower then 1, so the for-loop not run.
2. The loop should end when there are no more questions or when Cancel is clicked, is that right?

Statements:

1. Your code returns nothing when the loop ends (no more questions). So you become `undefined`
2. You do nothing with the entries, so the answers are always lost! (do you want return the answers at the end? Do you want return the answers only if entered these for all questions? (Otherwise `return 0`)?)

Solutions:

1. simply return object (`cancel` and `answers`)

```
function p(questions) {
    var answers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        let userAnswer = prompt(questions[i]);
        if (userAnswer === null) {
            return { cancel: true, answers: answers };
        } else {
            answers.push(userAnswer);
        }
    }
    return { cancel: false, answers: answers };
}

var questions = [ "Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3" ];
console.log(p(questions));
```

In this code you have:

3 Questions
the p() function asks all questions until <kbd>cancel</kbd> clicked.

It returns an object with 2 Properties:

`cancel`: `true` if cancel button clicked, otherwise `false`
`answers`: An array with the list of the answers in the same order like the questions (all or the first x until click cancel).

---

2. fully return object with all informations `cancel`, `questions` and `answers`

```
function p(questions) {
    var results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        let userAnswer = prompt(questions[i]);
        if (userAnswer === null) {
            return { cancel: true, results: results };
        } else {
            results.push( { question: questions[i], answer: userAnswer } );
        }
    }
    return { cancel: false, results: results };
}

var questions = [ "Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3" ];
console.log(p(questions));
```

This returns an object with 2 Properties:

`cancel`: same as above (`true` = cancel button clicked)
`results`: an array with the property `question` that contains the original question and `answer` that contains the entered answer.

Like:

```
{
  "cancel": false,
  "results": [
    { "question": "Question 1", "answer": "a" },
    { "question": "Question 2", "answer": "" },
    { "question": "Question 3", "answer": "c" }
  ]
}
```

Nothing entered == empty string
Cancel button clicked, `results` does not contain the remaining questions.
If you have no questions in `questions[]` the return was always `cancel: false` and `answers: []` oder `results: []`.